# How do I buy games in the form of PSN codes?

Tags: psn

I'm fairly new to PlayStations in general and was wondering how I can buy a game from the PSN in the form of a code? For example, if I buy ClaDun x2 or some other game, instead of it going to my account, I want it in the form of a redeemable code that I will probably give to somebody in the future, like a gift, or probably to trade with their other games? I came from Steam so I'm not sure how Sony does it in their system.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as gifts on the PSN, but you could buy a PSN funds card and gift it to someone. Whether that person buys the correct game or not, however, is a different story altogether, I'm afraid.

Comment: You found a solution? Is it still valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can get codes trough third party sites. I know you could get PS4 game codes on Amazon, looks like its available for all the PS4 games([Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n:6427831011,k:ps4%20games&keywords=ps4%20games&ie=UTF8&qid=1386337605&rnid=2941120011))

Them might as well sell codes for PS3 but I doubt it. Never encounter this alternative buying games for the PS3

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they still do but Gamestop sells DLC and you get a redeem code on the receipt. They don't sell all DLC though.

Comment: No I don't mean DLCs, I mean full games.

Comment: They sell full games too as DLC. Just not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into GAME stores they sell specific cards with download content on. They also sell them as a bundle sometimes on pre owned games. They stick the card in the cover to buy both at the same time.